# How do I warp to the original dimension in the 20w14infinite snapshot of Minecraft Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was playing around with the Minecraft April Fools 20w14infinite snapshot, mainly using the `/warp` command to warp to other dimensions.

The Minecraft Wiki provides many different easter egg dimensions that can be accessed with a certain target string to warp to the easter egg dimension.

But however, there is no documented warp target string that will let you return to your normal dimension and spawn.

Is there any way using `/warp` to return to the normal spawn dimension *without* using `/kill @s`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the warp codes that equate to the three vanilla dimensions:

- Overworld is `ballooning jade's`
- The Nether is `x[ko@`
- The End is `abatised redivides`

I found the warp codes for Overworld and The End on the Internet.

To find the warp code for the Nether was trickier. When you write a warp, minecraft adds `:why_so_salty#LazyCrypto` to it and converts it to sha256. The world number is determined by sha256, with Nether being 0, Overworld being 1, and The End being 2.

Sha256 is a cryptographically strong hash function and it is difficult to crack. I used a Python program to find the warp code for The Nether.

Resources I used:

- [Minecraft Wiki information](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_20w14%E2%88%9E)
- [SHA256 tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html)

The Python program I used:

```
from hashlib import sha256
import random
a = 0
b = 0
while a==0:
    str = ''.join(random.choice('!#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~') for i in range(5))
    str+=':why_so_salty#LazyCrypto'
    hash=sha256(str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    if hash[0:6]=='000000' and hash[6:8]=='00': a=1
    if hash[0:6]=='000000' and hash[6:8]=='80': a=1
    b+=1
    if b%1000000 == 0: print(b//1000000)
print(hash)
print(str)
```

Fun fact:`overworld:why_so_salty#LazyCrypto` produces `5f5e0a249b4b94c096d4b1106dcde007f902029b23fa8d9839a52dfa8474d055` or `DIM604659295`, which is generated randomly.

Comment: Very, very good work. I did not expect any warp codes to equate to any vanilla dimensions, considering that it's been a long while since the last answer. But now, a new question arises: if we can go to a *vanilla* dimension with `/warp`, can we go to an *easter-egg* dimension with `/execute in`? The answer might be blitheringly obvious, but I'm too lazy to go back and check that out.

Comment: End is 2? That's weird, considering its chunks are saved in "DIM-1".

Answer (score 4):

All the numerical dimension IDs (which all text input to `/warp` gets converted to, that's why `/warp overworld` doesn't work) are for either a randomly generated dimension or one of the easter egg dimensions. Overworld, Nether and End are not accessible this way.

You can use `/execute in overworld run tp @s ~ ~ ~`, but be careful, this puts you at the coordinates you currently are, but in the Overworld, it does not select a proper spawning location for you. You could use [`/spreadplayers`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spreadplayers) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/spreadplayers&oldid=1582062)), but even that behaves differently from `/warp` (for example if you use it in the Nether, it puts you on top of the bedrock roof).

Answer (score 2):

I've tried both `/warp overworld` and `/warp <world name>` (The world name for the world I was using was 'TEST'). It seems that /warp can't take you back. If you don't want to use `/kill`, then you will have to use a regular portal (No books). If you don't want to use `/kill` or portals, you won't be going to the overworld in that world.

Answer (score 1):

Using `execute in <dimension>` will run the command in that dimension. Therefore, the way to the return to the overworld:

```
/execute in minecraft:overworld run tp @s 0 100 0
```

Or if you know a set of coordinates in the OW, you can teleport there.